# Joomla 1.6 Auto Hyperlink Image to full Article

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6, joomla-article

I'm trying to have the first image on an article automatically link to the full article (similar to how wordpress 3.x works). This should work on Frontpage as well as Blog layout.

Basically I'm looking for a plugin like http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-summary/7233 but is compatible with Joomla 1.6. Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use CM Auto Read More for Joomla 1.6/1.7?

Here is a link to the developer's demo page:

http://demo.masterswebsitedesign.com/cmautoreadmore/

Here is the JED entry link:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-summary/17979

Comment: :( Sadly this option isn't free.